# Getting Selenium grid data via api?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Is it possible to programmatically (via an api perhaps) get info from the hub i.e what nodes are registered etc.

the ideal case i want to do this is to check programmatically how many requests are currently waiting for free nodes.

i know in the console (`/grid/console`) you can view this data in plain html. But is there a way to get this data via some api?